# jQuery add \n on keyevent Enter, send it to backend with \n

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea that lets the user cars into a list.
One car per row and after the user presses enter jQuery will add \n to move to the next row.

But when I collect this string the \n are "hidden" and i cannot get/print it. I need to send the cars to the webservice using \n as delimiter. Ex:

Skoda
Toyota
Seat

When printing in the log it will show like that. But i want it to be like:

Skoda\nToyota\nSeat

My current code lokes like:

```
        $('textarea').keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var s = $(this).val();
                var r = $(this).val(s+" \n");

                myconsolelog($(this).val());
            }
       });
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escape it, like:

```
var r = $(this).val(s+" \\n");
```

you mean like::

```
//for sending to backend
myconsolelog($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '\\n'));
```

As in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6hJCt/1/)

Comment: Thanks maybe I was not clear enough. When i present it to the user, i dont want the \n to be visible.

Comment: @d023h you meant something like that..?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to `Webservice`, even if you don't see it your string contains it,so **it will be sent** ,but if you just want to **display it**,i will then give more details :

In Unix and all Unix-like systems `\n` is the code for end-of-line,to tell the system that you want to show it , you should add an other `\` before:

```
 var r = $(this).val(s+" \\n");
```

**Example :**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('this is a \\n and this \n is for new line ');
</script>
```